# Curvilinear coordinates and constraint on $\phi$

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, curvilinear-coordinates

Why there is a constraint on $\phi$ which is $0\leq \phi \leq \pi?$ Why is it not $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi?$

My next question:-Let $P = (a,\theta,\phi)$ be a point in spherical coordinates, with a > 0  and $0<\phi < \pi.$ Then P lies on the sphere $\rho = a.$ Since $0 < \phi < \pi,$ the line segment from the origin to P can be extended to intersect the cylinder given by r = a (in cylindrical coordinates).

Find the cylindrical coordinates of that point of intersection.

How to answer this question? Answer given by author is $(a,\theta, a\cot\phi)$ and it is correct.

[image: Spherical coordinates]

Comment: What is $\phi $ in your first question???

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, I think you calls $\varphi$ in my post as $\phi$. Any way, if you observe the recently added figure to my post, you will find that it is the angle between the line segment and the positive z-axis.  I got the satisfactory answer to my first question after doing some trigonometric computational workings on my scientific, programmable calculator. But do you know how did the author computed the answer to my next question?